# An easy way to match dimensions between two data

Tags: python, list

**Inputs**

I have two lists

```
relation_path = [[[[15, 16, 14], [15, 16, 14]],
                  [[15, 13, 15], [15, 13, 15]],
                  [[14, 14, 16], [14, 14, 16]],
                  [[16, 12, 16], [16, 12, 16]]],
                 [[[15, 12], [15, 12]], 
                  [[14, 15], [14, 15]]]]

rules = [[('#1', 'X', 'Y'), ('#2', 'X', 'Z'), ('#3', 'Z', 'Y')],
         [('#1', 'X', 'Y'), ('#2', 'X', 'Y')]]
```

I'm going to use element of relation path as a pytorch model input.

first input is `relation_path[0]` as follow

first input is related with `rules[0]` and has 2 positive datas, 2 negative datas

```
relation_path[0] = [[[15, 16, 14], [15, 16, 14]],   #positive data1
                    [[15, 13, 15], [15, 13, 15]],   #positive data2
                    [[14, 14, 16], [14, 14, 16]],   #negative data1
                    [[16, 12, 16], [16, 12, 16]]]   #negative data2
```

and second input is `relation_path[1]` as follow

second input is related with `rules[1]` and has 1 positive data, 1 negative data

```
relation_path[1] = [[[15, 12], [15, 12]],    #positive data1
                    [[14, 15], [14, 15]]]    #negative data1
```

There is a problem where the first dimensions of the two inputs do not match.
So, I would like to do paddings on the second input to solve these problems.

**Output**

my desired output is as follow (1 is "PAD" token)

```
relation_path = [[[[15, 16, 14], [15, 16, 14]],
                  [[15, 13, 15], [15, 13, 15]],
                  [[14, 14, 16], [14, 14, 16]],
                  [[16, 12, 16], [16, 12, 16]]],
                 [[[15, 12], [15, 12]],
                  [[1, 1], [1, 1]],
                  [[14, 15], [14, 15]],
                  [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]]
```

My code is as follows.

```
max_positive_path = 2
neg_per_pos = 1
comp_each_rule = []
for rule in rules:
    comp_each_rule.append(len(rule))
    
single_template_size = 1 + (1 * neg_per_pos)
for rule_idx, relation_path_to_template in enumerate(relation_path):
    padded_rel_path = []
    num_pos_path = int(len(relation_path_to_template)/single_template_size)
    for i in range(0, len(relation_path_to_template), num_pos_path):
        padded_rel_path += relation_path_to_template[i:i+num_pos_path]
        for j in range(max_positive_path-num_pos_path):
            padding = np.ones((2,comp_each_rule[rule_idx]), dtype=int).tolist()
            padded_rel_path.append(padding)
        relation_path[rule_idx] = padded_rel_path
```

Is there a simpler way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think a library like `pandas` or `numpy` might be useful to deal with n-dimensional data.

If you want to add "rows" with `[1, 1]`, you can do that with a comprehension as well

```
rp = [[(cc + [[1, 1]]*len(cc[0])) if len(cc[0]) == 2 else cc] for ccc in relation_path for cc in ccc]
```

This, of course, will become cumbersome as you add more dimensions.